# How to display the data based on page refresh in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to build   an application in asp.net which displays the real time data .Assume this application as application which you typicaly see in DMV where it dsiplays which person has to go for which counter and what is the status.

what i currently have ?

1) data displaying from database and getting the real time data
  2) I am refreshing the page every 5 seconds

what i am trying to acheive?

1) Lest say i have 20 rows/persons . I want to display only 10 rows first and on page refresh next 10 rows and again on next page refresh go back to 1st 10 rows.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindQueueGrid();
        GetScrollInfo();
        gvwCourtRoomStatusInfo.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("font-size", "20px");

    }     


    private void BindQueueGrid()
    {
        List<TestClass> mydata = qService.GetData();
          Grid.DataSource = mydata;
         Grid.DataBind();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ViewState variable and switch it on each page load. Load the first 10 results on the first load, then on the refresh check the variable and load the second set of results. Mix in a little linq to get your query working.

```
 private void BindQueueGrid()
 {
    List<TestClass> mydata = qService.GetData();
    List<TestClass> onlyTen = new List<TestClass>();

    if(ViewState["check"] == null)
    {
       onlyTen = mydata.Take(10).ToList();
       Grid.DataSource = onlyTen;
       ViewState["check"] == true;
    }
    else
    {
       onlyTen = mydata.Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();
       Grid.DataSource = onlyTen;
       ViewState["check"] == null;
    }

     Grid.DataBind();

 }
```

You may be able to do it without the second list but I have not tested the code.

Comment: @Truckteck ..I was wondering if it works n number of rows or only 20 as static?

Comment: Your question was for 20 rows so that is what I included in my example. You can set the Skip() and Take() to any values you'd like. For example you can calculate the amount you skip based on the total size of your collection.